# Передача файла в ф-ию c++

Tags: c++, файлы, функции, динамические-массивы

Программа останавливается на строке `count = countFile(file);` Почему?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int countFile(ifstream& file)
{
int count=0;
while (!file.eof()) 
    count++;
return count;
}
int readFile(ifstream& file, int *a)
{
int i = 0;
while (!file.eof())
{
    file >> a[i];
    i++;
}
return *a;
}
int main()
{
ifstream file("f.txt");
ofstream fileout("g.txt");
int count;
count = countFile(file);
if (count % 2 == 1)
{
    cout << "Нечётное кол-во чисел! Измените кол-во чисел в файле." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}   
int *a = new int[count];
*a = readFile(file, a); 
for (int j = 0; j <count; j++) {
    cout << a[j] << " ";
}
file.close();
fileout.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

И как достичь конца файла, ничего не читая? Цикл

```
while (!file.eof()) count++;
```

крутится бесконечно, создавая впечатление "остановки"...

**Update**

*Если я правильно понял*, что должна делать ваша программа, то вот ее вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("f.txt");
    ofstream fileout("g.txt");
    int n, count = 0;
    while(file>>n)
    {
        ++count;
        fileout << n;
    }
    if (count % 2 == 1)
    {
        cout << "Нечётное кол-во чисел! Измените кол-во чисел в файле." << endl;
        fileout.close();
        _unlink("g.txt");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: разве не читает?
и как исправить?

Comment: Добавить `file.Read` в тело цикла

Comment: @Surv Напишите точно, что должна делать программа - тогда будет понятнее, что и как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

Код:

```
int main()
{
ifstream in; // Поток in будем использовать для чтения
ofstream out; // Поток out будем использовать для записи
out.open("output.txt");
in.open("input.txt");
char a[100];
int i,n,s;
char tmp;

n=-1;
while (!in.eof())    {
    n++;
    in>>tmp;
    if(!in.eof())
        a[n] = tmp;
}

s=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
// if (a[i]='8') s+=2;
//if (a[i]='6') s++;
//if (a[i]='9') s++;
out <<a[i];
 }
//out << s <<endl;
in.close();
out.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Лучше не `while (!in.eof())    {
    n++;
    in>>tmp;
    if(!in.eof())
        a[n] = tmp;
}`, а `n=0; while(in>>a[n]){ n++; }` - только зачем вообще читать в массив?... :)